# Integral over an ellipsoid of $z^2\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y$, Stokes' theorem

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be an ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leq1$. I explicitly computed $$\int_{\partial M} z^2\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y=0$$ Can one use Stokes' theorem here? I mean
$$\int_{\partial M} z^2\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y=\int_M 2z\mathrm{d}z\wedge\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y$$
so, can we conclude by symmetry of the domain, that the last integral is $0$? If yes, what kind of formal verifications are needed? I am sorry if this is completely trivial, just trying to find my way around this stuff.

Comment: What about considering the behavior of the original integral under $(x, y, z) \to (-x, y, -z)$?

Comment: I see. Is it not a coincidence, that there are such transformations on integrals of both sides of Stokes' formula?